# Airplay Mirroring XBMC addon

Tags: kodi, openelec

I have a model B raspberry pi running OpenELEC. I am aware that as standard Airplay is available in OpenELEC for youtube videos and pictures.

I want to use Airplay Mirroring on OpenELEC. Is there an addon for XBMC and OpenELEC to allow Airplay Mirroring?

Comment: "allow Airplay Mirroring" can you please expand? What device to what device?

Comment: @SomeRandomUser I want to use Airplay Mirroring from my windows laptop running airparrot to my raspberry pi running OpenELEC.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Seems rplay from vmlite is the only current option

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IOS9, it doesn't seem like there is any solution. However, I know that some people are working on it, so stay tuned to
[this website](https://github.com/juhovh/shairplay/issues/43) for more info.